# how to handle action notification from a native module to react native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder informativeNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder (reactContext,"channelId")
    .setSmallIcon (R.drawable.avatar)
    .setStyle (new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle ())
    .setContentIntent (pendingIntent)
    .setCustomContentView (collapseNotification)
    .setGroup (GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
    .setGroupSummary (true)
    .setPriority (NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    .setNumber (1)
    .setBadgeIconType (NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE)
    .addAction (sendEvent (reactContext,"action","message") )
    .setAutoCancel (true);
```

Make 'sendEvent' return 'androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Action'

```
  private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName,String message){
  WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap ();
  params.putString ("message",message);
  reactContext
    .getJSModule (DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
    .emit (eventName,params);
}
```

I would like to handle the notification action from the native module to react native.

Comment: Have you read through the native modules docs? https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: yes, I have read the documentation on native modules